# What can I do to prohibit text splitting when extracting text from PDF file using iText7?

Tags: vb.net, merge, itext7, text-extraction

I have written a little `VB.Net` program to extract text and info from `PDF` file using `iText7` API installed using Nuget.

When I run it, for a lot of strings, I get more than one string !

Example:

```
Left:   128,2880 /Right:   147,7406 /Top:   693,7059 /Bottom:   688,3118 /Text: [TRANSPO]
Left:   147,7384 /Right:   150,5556 /Top:   693,7059 /Bottom:   688,3118 /Text: [R]
Left:   150,4318 /Right:   153,0811 /Top:   693,7059 /Bottom:   688,3118 /Text: [T]
```

What can I do to prohibit text splitting ?

In example, the string is `TRANSPORT` and is equal of string displayed on second line in white cell.

I know that I can write a litte code to unsplit "badly" splitting strings; but in posting this question, I simply hope that `iText7` can simply do it himself.

[image]

The complete program is following

```vbnet
    Imports System.IO
    Imports System.Net
    Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
    Imports iText.Kernel.Pdf
    Imports iText.Kernel.Pdf.Canvas.Parser
    Imports iText.Kernel.Pdf.Canvas.Parser.Listener
    Imports System.Text
    Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
    Imports iText.StyledXmlParser.Jsoup.Nodes
    Imports iText.Kernel.Utils
    Imports iText.Kernel.Geom
    Imports iText.Kernel.Pdf.Canvas.Parser.Data
    Imports iText.Commons.Utils
    Imports iText.IO.Util
    Imports Org.BouncyCastle.Math.EC
    Imports System.ComponentModel
    Imports iText.StyledXmlParser.Jsoup
    
    Module MainModule
    
        Public Class XEventListener
            Implements IEventListener
    
            Private oInfoList As New List(Of TextRenderInfo)
    
            Public Function getResultantTextWithPosition() As List(Of TextRenderInfo)
                Return oInfoList
            End Function
    
            Private Sub RenderText(t As TextRenderInfo)
                If t.GetText().Trim().Length() = 0 Then Return
    
                oInfoList.Add(t)
            End Sub
    
            Public Sub EventOccurred(data As IEventData, type As EventType) Implements IEventListener.EventOccurred
                Dim t As TextRenderInfo = data
                t.PreserveGraphicsState()
                Call RenderText(t)
            End Sub
    
            Public Function GetSupportedEvents() As ICollection(Of EventType) Implements IEventListener.GetSupportedEvents
                Dim collection As New List(Of EventType)
                collection.Add(EventType.RENDER_TEXT)
                Return collection
            End Function
        End Class
    
        Public Sub Main()
            Dim sPdfFile as String = "CinéTéléRevue.2023-01-19.pdf"
    
            Using oReader As PdfReader = New PdfReader(sPdfFile)
                Using pdfDocument As PdfDocument = New PdfDocument(oReader)
                    For pageNum As Integer = 1 To pdfDocument.GetNumberOfPages
                        Dim page As PdfPage = pdfDocument.GetPage(pageNum)
                        Call ExtractPage(page)
                    Next pageNum
                End Using
            End Using
        End Sub
    
        Private Sub ExtractPage(page As PdfPage, sTitle As String)
            Dim sNewPage As String = sPdfFile.Replace(".pdf", "") & "." & sTitle & ".pdf"
    
            Using oWriter As New PdfWriter(sNewPage)
                Using pdfDocument As New PdfDocument(oWriter)
                    pdfDocument.AddPage(page.CopyTo(pdfDocument))
                    pdfDocument.Close()
                End Using
            End Using
    
            Dim listener As New XEventListener()
            Dim processor As New PdfCanvasProcessor(listener)
            processor.ProcessPageContent(page)
            Dim t1 As TextRenderInfo
    
            sNewPage = sPdfFile.Replace(".pdf", "") & "." & sTitle & ".info"
            Using sw As New StreamWriter(sNewPage)
                Dim result = listener.getResultantTextWithPosition()
                For Each t As TextRenderInfo In result
                    Dim ascent As LineSegment = t.GetAscentLine()
                    Dim descent As LineSegment = t.GetDescentLine()
    
                    Dim initX As Single = descent.GetStartPoint().Get(0)
                    Dim initY As Single = descent.GetStartPoint().Get(1)
                    Dim endX As Single = ascent.GetEndPoint().Get(0)
                    Dim endY As Single = ascent.GetEndPoint().Get(1)
    
                    Dim rect As Rectangle = New Rectangle(initX, initY, endX - initX, endY - initY)
    
                    Dim iLeft As Single = rect.GetLeft()
                    Dim iRight As Single = rect.GetRight()
                    Dim iTop As Single = rect.GetTop()
                    Dim iBottom As Single = rect.GetBottom()
    
                    Dim sLine As String = ""
                    sLine &= "Left: " & iLeft.ToString("0.0000").PadLeft(10) & " /"
                    sLine &= "Right: " & iRight.ToString("0.0000").PadLeft(10) & " /"
                    sLine &= "Top: " & iTop.ToString("0.0000").PadLeft(10) & " /"
                    sLine &= "Bottom: " & iBottom.ToString("0.0000").PadLeft(10) & " /"
                    sLine &= "Text: [" & t.GetText() & "]"
    
                    sw.WriteLine(sLine)
                Next
                sw.Close()
            End Using
        End Sub
    
    End Module
```

Comment: *"What can I do to prohibit text splitting ?"* - The text is split up because in your source pdf the text ist drawn in those split up portions. To *prohibit text splitting*, therefore, you have to tell the producer of the pdf not to create pdfs with strong drawing split up like that. IText itself in its text extraction strategies combines text pieces. As you have your own listener, you have to combine yourself.

Comment: @mkl: that is what I done ! Thanks. I have written a little program to merge splitted text.